VS Code sticky scroll line length horizontal cutoff
The sticky scroll line does not shows the full line. Instead it shows |Show more (1.4 KB)| at the end of the line and when I click it, the page will scroll back to line 0.
Normal:

Sticky scroll:

I tried searching the settings but found nothing relevant in the gui based settings.
Is there a possibility that this line size can be set higher?

Do you mean "column 0" instead of "line 0"?

No, I meant line 0. When I scroll down in the csv, rainbow csv shows the column names in the sticky scroll. But because there are too many columns, the sticky scroll line is not showing fully. Instead, it shows the |Show more (71 chars)|. Is there a way to make the sticky scroll length bigger?
